# Python Function to Match Two Columns Between Dataframes and Add Another Column to First Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as below, df1 and df2. I am looking to match two columns between these df's and then add a new column to df1 which includes other column data from df2. In this case df2 is in effect reference data and I am looking to add data from here to df1.

df1 =

| Column A1 | Column B1 |
| --- | --- |
| x | 2 |
| y | 3 |

df2 =

| Column A2 | Column B2 | Column C2 | Column D2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| w | 1 | abc | usd |
| x | 2 | def | eur |
| y | 3 | ghi | gbp |
| z | 4 | jkl | nzd |

In this case the match would be between df1[A1,B1] and df2[A2, B2] - where these match, the value from df2[D2] is taken and added to df1:

target_output =

| Column A1 | Column B1 | Column D2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 2 | eur |
| y | 3 | gbp |

NB: The dfs are not of the same the length.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

I have tried matching and working through df1iteratively however receive errors when applying conditions for multiple matching. I also tried using df2 as a dictionary and referencing however I am still struggling to implement the multiple conditions on the match. I also attempted to merge the data frames however this returned multiple errors both in implementing logic and type errors between dfs.

Comment: why would you have Cell 6 in the second row in D2? You likely want a left [`merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: ** Have changed column values for more clarity.

x = df1.merge(df, how='left', left_on=(['Column A1', 'Column B'])1 right_on=(['Column A2', 'Column B2']) )

When running this the added columns that are returned only contain NaN values.

Comment: Then it's a merge, see duplicate link

Comment: x = df1.merge(df, how='left', left_on=(['Column A1', 'Column B'])1 right_on=(['Column A2', 'Column B2']) )

When running this the added columns that are returned only contain NaN values - any idea if this would be incorrect?